# Loop in NuxtJS (Vue) outputs wrong data

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following data:

```
export const myData = [
{
    id: 1,
    lang: "it",
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "IT Page1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "IT Page2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "IT Page3",
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    lang: "en",
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "EN Page1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "EN Page2",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "EN Page3",
        }
    ]
}
]
```

my loop does the following:

```html
<ul v-for="(item, i) in myData" :key="i">
  <li>{{ item.items[i].title }}</li>
</ul>
```

and outputs only:

```
IT Page1
EN Page2
```

but (the loop above) should output all data for both languages, right? Also, how can i choose language (statically or dynamically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make two loops and render the selected language conditionally using `v-if` :

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in myData" :key="i">
 <template v-if="item.lang==='it'"> 
  <ul v-for="(subItem, j) in item.items" :key="j">
     <li>{{ subItem.title }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: you're welcome, what do you mean by select language?

Comment: @mam code highlight? Usually you can try "3 backticks" and + `html` or `js`. I've edited your initial question if you want to edit and check how to achieve it.

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim, I mean something like if lang === "it" show only the items of that language.